# Can't connect to postgresql server installed locally on my machine

Tags: postgresql, rest, database-connection

I have installed the DSP(Dreamfactory Service Platform) locally on my Mac Book Pro using Bitnani.

I have a PostGreSQL server running locally on my Macbook, which I want to connect to using the DSP.
I am successfully able to connect to my PostGreSQL server from other applications, which essentially means that there is no problem with the setup.
However, on trying to connect the same from DSP I get the error:- "Failed to launch service "sql": CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection."

My connection string is :- "pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=Pinu"
Also, the password has been correctly entered.

The port is default as 5432. Whether or not I enter the same in the connection string, the connection always fails.

Even though I am trying to add the service as Remote SQL DB, I know that it's actually on the same local host. Not sure if that is the issue.

I also tried entering - 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost, but still I see the same issue.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After talking to you via email, it looks like the root issue here is that you haven't successfully upgraded your DSP to the latest version. We are releasing DreamFactory version 1.8 on Bitnami tomorrow, so you should upgrade to the latest version.

As far as your PostgreSQL issue let's explore some options:

> 1) Connection strings:
>
> a) pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=Pinu
>   b)
>   pgsql:host=localhost:5432;dbname-Pinu
>   c)
>   pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=Pinu
>
> 2) If these don't work, try substituting your localhost with
>   127.0.0.1 (as you've tried previously, but test this in all scenarios).
>
> 3)
>   pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=series1;schema=schema_name_here

Typically, Option A should work without a problem.

Give these a try if you would, and if you need some help upgrading then reach out to me again via email.

--Thanks,
Mark